# Out of system resources

Tags: ms-word

I have recently run into an error message

[image]

when working with a word document. A brief research gave me this [MS article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/211489). I am using Word 2010 32bit on a 16GB-RAM-machine and this particular document is far below the limits mentioned in that article. What am I missing here? What else could cause this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the reason for this and other similar errors - the [GDI Objects](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724291%28VS.85%29.aspx). Word runs to the limit of GDIs, which by default is only 10000. One can change the corresponding registry setting

```
GDIProcessHandleQuota
```

under

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Windows
```

Increasing this value solved my problem. Many thanks to Mark Russinovich and [his blog](http://blogs.technet.com/b/markrussinovich/archive/2008/07/21/3092070.aspx) for the help in understanding memory management in windows.